# How can I automatically change RStudio's options?

Tags: rstudio, windows-server-2008

I use RStudio on a shared Windows server. I prefer to not have auto-matched parentheses when I code in RStudio. I know I can turn that option off through Tools >> Options >> Code >> Editing >> Insert matching parens/quotes. However, whenever I log onto the server and open RStudio for the first time during a session on that server, all of the changes I made to RStudio's options the last time I was on the server have been reset. Is there a way to ensure that my preferences for RStudio's options persist over time? I do not have admin access to this server, so that may limit my options.

I looked into R profiles and created one to permanently set some options for R, but I did not find any way to set RStudio options that way.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Global options are stored in a subdirectory described in https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State.  On my Mac it is ~/.rstudio-desktop.

This is not part of the RStudio documented behaviour, so it may change, but I see the setting in the file 
`.rstudio-desktop/monitored/user-settings/user-settings`
This is a plain text file; it looks like YAML to me.  The setting you want is in the `uiPrefs` entry in that file.

What I'd recommend is that you follow the instructions on the web page I mentioned for making a backup of your settings, then restore them when you move to a new machine.  If you are very adventurous you could try editing that file, but don't expect it to be easy.